# Filter entries by multiple field ranges

Tags: entries, filter

I am trying to filter entries based on multiple field value ranges.
For example: All entries where my `customField (type: number) is between 0 and 10 OR 20 and 25`.

It's straightforward to filter by one range:

```
{% set results = craft.entries({
  customField: ['and', '>= 0', '< 10']
}) %}
```

How would I add multiple ranges for the same field to the above query?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do both an "and" and an "or" in a single query going though the ElementCriteriaModel.

Here are a few other posts that go into more detail and provide some potential workarounds.

[How can I create an ElementCriteriaModel with 'and' and 'or'](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4560/how-can-i-create-an-elementcriteriamodel-with-and-and-or)

[How to fetch specific users OR admins with the ElementCriteriaModel?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/587/how-to-fetch-specific-users-or-admins-with-the-elementcriteriamodel)